# I don't understand what I did wrong?

Tags: r, latex, pdflatex

After compiling, I got the following messages:

## Error message

```
Error: LaTeX failed to compile hw_ch_1_Hussein_Jafar.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
```

## Warning message

```
In addition: Warning message:
In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Execution halted

No LaTeX installation detected (LaTeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a LaTeX distribution for your platform: https://www.latex-project.org/get/

  If you are not sure, you may install TinyTeX in R: tinytex::install_tinytex()

  Otherwise consider MiKTeX on Windows - http://miktex.org

  MacTeX on macOS - https://tug.org/mactex/
  (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome _strongly_ recommended)

  Linux: Use system package manager
```

Comment: Did you install LaTeX? If not install as suggested in your error message

Comment: That looked like a fairly informative message. Did you read it? If so, what did you do in response to the message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you don't have a Latex installation in your machine. I suppose you're running with a linux distribution, try from the terminal to install the complete texlive package to avoid potential issues related to Latex installation:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install texlive-full
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).